# How to import playlists from Rhythmbox into Banshee?

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee

Since Banshee became the default player in Natty, I want to import my playlists from Rhythmbox. Banshee offers an 'import playlists' feature but it does not recognize Rhythmbox's playlists (in folder home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~/.local/share/rhythmbox` playlists are on a `playlists.xml` file. I think Banshee can't import `.xml` files, but `.pls` files, wich are the default Rhythbox playlists format when you SAVE them.

So I believe you have to install Rhythmbox, save every playlist and then, import them from Banshee. I might be wrong, but I think it's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your playlist from Rhythmbox to a file (in .m3u or .pls format) before you can import this file in Banshee.